# Trouble publishing notebooks to cloud that contain Manipulate Entities

Tags: publishing

As shown here:

> [image]

My functions `disp` and `man` (defined above in the notebook) aren't evaluated when published the cloud/viewable in a webpage.  How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set the `SaveDefinitions -> True` option in your Manipulate function.  See http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SaveDefinitions.html

Comment: Still does not appear to be working: https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/george.w.singer/Published/CayleysFormula.nb

Comment: @George your link and both deployments look ok to me, or?